# Why this method using reflections throws npe?

Tags: java, reflection

I have some `static final String` fields and I want to get their values using reflection so I made a method like this:

```
public String getLogoSrc(final String provider) {
    if (provider.equals(StringUtils.EMPTY)) {
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    logger.info("---provider is: "+provider);

    for (Field f : ConstantsBean.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        if (f.getName().contains(provider.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "_"))) {
            try {
                return f.get(null) != null?  f.get(null).toString() : "";
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return StringUtils.EMPTY;
}
```

I simply don't understand why I always receive NPE when trying to return the value:

`return f.get(null) != null?  f.get(null).toString() : "";`

Exception is:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl
.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccess
orImpl.java:18)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
        at com.gravitant.cloud.common.jsf.core.beans.ConstantsBean.getLogoSrc(Co
nstantsBean.java:195)
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print the field before accessing it. I suspect you're trying to access a non-static field, and passing null to `field.get()` is thus not acceptable.

Comment: You're right. I was having a not static field too which matched the condition, and togheter with my passing of `get(null)`, it throws exceptions. The solution was not to stop doing `get(null)` but also checking the type of the field to be of my static field type.

Comment: @CristianBoariu Check if it is static: `if (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()))`

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

`get(Object obj)`

> If the specified obj argument is null, the method throws a
>   NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing null as the specified object. i.e. you're doing this:

```
null.fieldname
```

You need to pass in the *reference* to the object that you want the field of. That field object represents a generic field, not the field on a particular object.

The same applies to methods via reflection. You have to pass in the reference of the object that you want to apply the method *to*.

Answer (score 0):

when you call field.get(obj) with

**Parameters:**
obj - object from which the represented field's value is to be extracted

**Returns:**
the value of the represented field in object obj; primitive values are wrapped in an appropriate object before being returned

**Throws:**
`IllegalAccessException` - if the underlying field is inaccessible.

`IllegalArgumentException` - if the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field (or a subclass or implementor thereof).

`NullPointerException` - if the specified object is null and the field is an instance field.

`ExceptionInInitializerError` - if the initialization provoked by this method fails.